# Eclipse program wont run

Tags: java, android, eclipse, apk

Everytime i tried to Run my APK via eclipse i get

```
[2012-05-31 10:09:54 - DZC68] Performing sync
[2012-05-31 10:09:57 - DZC68] Uploading DZC68.apk onto device '0019eb16662fae'
[2012-05-31 10:09:57 - DZC68] Installing DZC68.apk...
[2012-05-31 10:10:00 - DZC68] Success!
```

it wont lauch my APK on my mobile phone (SGS2) or Android Emulator. A other APK i get

```
[2012-05-31 10:01:18 - VoetbalCoachWNS] Performing voetbalcoah.wns.VoetbalCoachWNSActivity activity launch
[2012-05-31 10:01:20 - VoetbalCoachWNS] Uploading VoetbalCoachWNS.apk onto device '0019eb16662fae'
[2012-05-31 10:01:20 - VoetbalCoachWNS] Installing VoetbalCoachWNS.apk...
[2012-05-31 10:01:22 - VoetbalCoachWNS] Success!
[2012-05-31 10:01:22 - VoetbalCoachWNS] Starting activity voetbalcoah.wns.VoetbalCoachWNSActivity on device 0019eb16662fae
```

This works fine. it will start the APK on my phone and on the Emulator

Answer (score 1):

Please try these steps; this might help you out:

Go to Project->Properties

Select Android from left-hand side list

Uncheck the "Is Library" checkbox

Comment: ohk deleting the R.Java file in /Gen folder did the trick for me many time try this...

Comment: It seems this wasnt the problem to :( damn

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your manifest has declared Launcher activity with following intent filter.

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```